# INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'double' in R?

Tags: r, integer, double

I have got a data.frame "data1" made up of 16 variables (columns) and 64 observations (rows). The variables take 0 or 1 value, for presence and absence of the variables (o is the outcome variable):

```
x    y    z    o
1    0    1    1
1    1    1    1
0    0    1    1
0    1    0    1
1    0    0    1
1    1    0    1
0    0    0    1
0    0    1    1
```

The data file was an excel file that I imported into R as .csv file. I changed the name of the variables to shorter ones using the following code:

```
require(dplyr)
library(QCA)
cleaned_data <- data1 %>% 
dplyr::rename_(
'x'  = 'treatmentconcerns.revelationabout',
'y'  = 'treatmentconcerns.familyconcerns',
'z'  = 'treatmentconcerns.familyemotional',
'o'  = 'outcmomy'
 )
```

I am going to do a Qualitative Comparative Analysis (QCA) analysis using the following code:

```
data1NR <- superSubset(cleaned_data, outcome = "OUTC", incl.cut = 0.9, cov.cut = 0.5)
```

But R brings the following error and I don't know how to solve it:

```
Error in superSubset(cleaned_data, outcome = "OUTC", incl.cut = 0.9, cov.cut = 0.5) : 
INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'double'
```

I used:

```
str()
```

to see what is the structure of my data and it says that all my variables are integer, but I am stuck and don't figure out why this error comes back?

Can anyone help me to solve it? I searched in the previous questions but could not find an answer that can work for my case.

Thanks in advance,
Eshmel

[image: Codes]

[image: codes]

Comment: What is the output of `str(cleaned_data)`?

Comment: More than likely your data is not an integer, but a double.  Just use as.integer for all your variables.

Comment: @NelsonGon the output is all variables are integer, but I get that error still.

Comment: Could you try to see if my answer helps? I couldn't reproduce your problem once renaming was done right. Please edit to add the output of `str(cleaned_data)`.

Comment: @thc I did, but the error is there again.

Comment: Also there is no variable name "OUTC" at least in the sample data you provide hence the outcome argument in superSubset cannot return anything.

Comment: @NelsonGon The problem is not with OUTC, that is o in fact. Can I send you my data and code so that you can take look at? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could edit to add the output of `dput(head(df,20))` to the question.

Comment: @NelsonGon, I did it and used 'dput(head(df, 20))' , but it does not work either.

Comment: Oh, 20 is an arbitrary number. I just assumed your data set is large. Replace it with any number(depending on the number of rows in your data set and add the output to the question. Just type `dput(head(cleaned_data,5))`

Comment: @NelsonGon, I changed the number according to my row numbers (in the first attempt in deed), but it does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: Wow, what does it say?

Comment: @NelsonGon Exactly the same error as before:

Comment: @NelsonGon: Error in superSubset(datas, outcome = "OUTC", incl.cut = 0.9, cov.cut = 0.5) : 
  INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'double'

Comment: `dput` returns the same error? `dput` is supposed to return what your data looks like. I just can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: @NelsonGon, Yes,    'dput'   returns same error.

Comment: Add a screenshot of all your commands to the question.

Comment: @NelsonGon, Thanks Nelson, I think I have to work with STATA, maybe I will not see such a problem there.

Comment: Ok, Good luck then.

Comment: @NelsonGon, I added the screenshot. Thanks for all help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188170/discussion-between-nelsongon-and-eshmel).

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is at the naming part:
The name should come first and not sure if it worked for you:

```
df %>% 
  rename(Treatment=x)
```

In your case you would need something like:

```
clean<-df %>% 
  rename(
    treatmentconcerns.revelationabout=x,
     treatmentconcerns.familyconcerns=y,
    treatmentconcerns.familyemotional=z,
    outcmomy=o)
```

This works for me:

```
superSubset(clean, outcome ="outcmomy", incl.cut = 0.9, cov.cut = 0.5)

                                                                                                         inclN  RoN    covN  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1  TREATMENTCONCERNS.REVELATIONABOUT+treatmentconcerns.familyconcerns+treatmentconcerns.familyemotional  1.000  0.000  1.000 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```